# Generating pdf before leaving a page in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

After submitting a form and before Redirecting a page need to generate a pdf, ask the user to save the file, then redirect the page .

Below is my code

```
  DataSet objData = objInsert.Execute();

  DocLib dl = new DocLib();

  System.IO.MemoryStream ms = dl.GenerateForm(objData.Tables[0].Rows[0]);

  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" +OrderNo + ".pdf");
  Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
  Response.OutputStream.Flush();
  Response.OutputStream.Close();

  Response.Redirect("OrderList.aspx");
```

But currently once the save dialog box appears the page stops navigation and remains in the same page.  How to redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a reason to effect Redirect's work. As another solution, you can try this.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page),"navigation",
         "<script>window.location.href='OrderList.aspx'</script>")
```